# /quiet and /qn options don't seem to work for /x{guid} for an installer created with WIX

Tags: wix

**Edited as I found out it does work when executed As Administrator**

Please be kind as I'm still very new to Wix installers so it's not wholly clear to me how to ask this efficiently.

Having said that....

I created a .wixproj and it's working fine. When I run the .msi it generates, it installs the product and all the files are there. The product Id is set to a {guid}.

When I run **msiexec.exe /x{guid}** it works fine. It shows the UI to ask the user whether they want to uninstall the product and when they confirm, it uninstalls it.

When I run **msiexec.exe /x{guid} /passive** it works fine. The UI pops up and shows the user that it's uninstalling the product.

**As Administrator:**
When I run **msiexec.exe /x{guid} /q** it works as long as I run it with elevated privileges, for example from a Command Prompt launched **"As Administrator"**.

**Not As Administrator:**
When I run msiexec.exe /x{guid} /qn or /quiet or /qn /passive .... it just returns straight to the command line, and the product remains installed, even though I **installed** the product without elevated privileges.

Is there some property I can set in my .wxs file to get msiexec /x{guid} /q to work, even if it's called by a user without elevated privileges?

I'll be very happy to add code snippets from my .wxs file here but I'm not sure what to include. Here's one part:

```
<Product Id="guid here"
         Name="our name here"
         Language="1033"
         Version="5.9.2.65"
         Manufacturer="our company here"
         UpgradeCode="a different guid here">
    <Package InstallerVersion="500"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine"
             Platform="x86" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MSI is declared `perMachine` (see the `Package/@InstallScope`). If you want the package to be able to be managed by non-administrators then you'll need to change that to `perUser`.

Note: per-user packages will not prompt for elevation thus will not be able to install to per-machine locations.

It isn't clear to me what you did to install a `perMachine` package without administrative rights or an elevation prompt but you didn't provide details about that in your question.

PS: None of this is about the WiX Toolset. This is all about Windows Installer behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question perfectly. You are absolutely right: I am a local admin on the machine I tested this on and UAC had been disabled, on machines with UAC the user will be prompted accordingly. Should I change anything in this question (tags?) to make it more relevant to what it's really about?

Comment: No, you've now explained why perMachine worked on your machine without UAC prompts: you turned off UAC.  Sounds like everything is behaving exactly correctly.